# Comparing Strings with equivalent but different Unicode code points in Java/Kotlin

Tags: java, string, kotlin, character-encoding, contains

I ran into an issue while comparing two strings with different coders. My code is actually in Kotlin but it's running on the JVM and is effectively using Java's String implementation. Also, my question is of a more general nature and my actual code will not be of concern.

The problem is that I have two strings, lets say `a` and `b`, where

```
a = "something something äöü something"
b = "äöü"
```

you'd expect that `a.contains(b)` returns `true`, and that is the case if you retrieve your strings like shown above. But in my case, the strings come from different sources and happen to have different coders. String `a` has the coder `1`, which is `UTF16`, and String `b` has the coder `0`, which is `LATIN1`. In this case, `a.contains(b)` returns false. Now you might have noticed that I included special characters (`ä`, `ö` and `ü`), because that is where, according to my debugging, the comparison fails.

While I am at the stackframe where the `a.contains(b)` call happens, both strings appear correctly displayed in my debugger (IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2020.2). However if I subsequently step into the comparing functions, I notice that in `java.lang.StringLatin1.regionMatchesCI_UTF16()`, where the byte arrays are converted back char by char, the special characters of `b` are now not correct (`ä` -> `a`, `ö` -> `o`, `ü` -> `u`). And of course the comparison fails then.

Now as I said, both strings are displayed correctly in the debugger originally, so the information has to be somewhere. My question is: what do I have to do to let the `a.contains(b)` call return `true`, as expected?

EDIT:

I was certain that the problem would originate from the strings having two different coders. However, even though the different coders *hint* at the fact that different encodings were at work, they are not the *source* of the problem. Generally speaking, different coders do not affect the result of `.equals()`, `.contains()` or similar calls. @OrangeDog pointed this out, while also suggesting that I actually ended up with two different representations of the same character, which really was the case. And still, my question remains the same: How do I compare these two strings that are "semantically" the same, but differ in the representation of certain characters?

- Java 11 (11.0.2, openJDK 11)
- Kotlin/JVM 1.4.0
- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2020.2

Comment: When you say *coder*, do you mean *encoding*?

Comment: well yes, because `coder` is the name of the `private int` field of `java.lang.String`, which determines the encoding. It can either be `LATIN1` (magic constant for 0) or `UTF16` (magic constant for 1).

Comment: What do you mean "effectively using Java's String implementation"? Either you are or you aren't.

Comment: @OrangeDog Kotlin is (by now) multiplatform and may have different implementations for the same class depending on the platform it runs on. Even though I use `kotlin.String`, the actual implementation that gets "plugged in" because I compile for JVM is `java.lang.String`

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example. It's difficult to work from hypothetical situations.

Comment: "my actual code will not be of concern" - it should be, because your example does not reproduce the problem

Comment: @AdamMillerchip: I don't think your edit is entirely correct. There *is* an internal field `coder` in `java.lang.String` that's not directly related to the user-visible notion of encodings. And I think the original description referred to that field.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. I thought the issue seems to be that the strings have different code points, and the implementation of String seems to be a distraction. It's difficult to tell without a reproducible example though.

Comment: The question should be: 1) Here's is how string `a` is created. 2) Here is how string `b` is created. 3) What do I need to do to ensure `a.contains(b)` is `true`? Both 1 and 2 are missing right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignore the internal details of `String`. As far as you are concerned it does not have an encoding, it just stores sequences of characters (or "code point units" as the Kotlin docs describe them).

I'm guessing one of your strings (that was Latin-1) uses the character `U+00E4` (ä) and the other uses the sequence `U+0061` `U+0308` (ä). You can verify using `toCharArray()`.

To be able to compare such strings sensibly, there is the class [`java.text.Normalizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Normalizer.html):

```java
Normalizer.normalize(a, Form.NFKD).contains(Normalizer.normalize(b, Form.NFKD))
```

Or, ensure that any Strings you are receiving are already in the recommended `NFC` form.

Comment: String `a` actually encodes `ö` as a sequence of the chars 111 and 776 (0x6F 0x308) and String `b` encodes it as a single character, 246 (0xF6). So I guess you're right. But semantically speaking (or the way they're displayed), they are still the same. And that was actually my question: how can I bring the `contains()` method to return `true`? Is there a way to convert `a`'s representation to that of `b` (or vice versa)?

Comment: Yes, those are semantically identical. There are some corner case places where you want to distinguish them, but they are by far the minority (and even that's usually more about other ligatures and not those specific characters).

Comment: @OrangeDog well done for working out what the question should have been :)

Comment: And just to expand on the use of Normalizer: it's a good idea to apply the normalizer at the boundary of your system and don't try to use it at every comparison point. If you make sure to only ever handle Strings with the same normalization applied, then you can forget about it again.